# parsing an auto generated html file

Tags: html-parsing

```
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<td>
    <div align="center">
        <font face="Arial" size="2">1</font>
    </div>
</td>

<td>
    <div align="left">
        <font face="Arial" size="2">
            <a href="displayCompany.php?name=AAMRATECH " target="_self" class="ab1">AAMRATECH
            </a>
        </font>
    </div>
</td>
```

i have an html file like this. from where i want to retrieve the company name, share price and other values. there isn't any id or name attribute to retrieve this information easily. can you suggest me how to do this?

N.B. i want to use javascript/ jquery / php framework.

Answer (score 0):

In general, seeing you dont say anything about a language or a more specific situation, you can use [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to select the values you want.